GitLab kubernetes runner binary not found during testing stage
I am learning GitLab CI/CD and have deployed a Kubernetes runner that I am using for my pipelines.
In the first stage, I build a .deb package of iperf3 for Ubuntu, which is then copied as an artifact and installed during the testing stage.
However, after the package is installed, the iperf3 binary is nowhere to be found. I have replicated the steps manually and in Docker, and the .deb package appears to be valid and works fine in other environments. I can't figure out why the binary disappears during the CI test pipeline.
I even tried unpacking the .deb package inside the testing stage, and the data.tar.xz file, which does contain the binary, though it appears empty or incomplete. I have never seen this behaviour anywhere else before.
.gitlab-ci.yml CICD code
stages:
  - build
  - test
  
build_job:
  stage: build
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  script:
    - echo "Initiating build stage on $(date)"
    - apt update && apt install -y build-essential wget
    - wget -P tmp/ https://downloads.es.net/pub/iperf/iperf-3.9.tar.gz
    - tar -xvf tmp/iperf-3.9.tar.gz -C tmp/
    - mkdir build pkg
    - tmp/iperf-3.9/configure --prefix=/build
    - make && make install
    - mkdir build/DEBIAN
    - |
      echo "Package: iperf3
      Version: 3.9-1
      Section: utils
      Priority: optional
      Architecture: all
      Maintainer: LMAO <lol@lmao.com>
      Description: iperf 3.9 test build" > build/DEBIAN/control
    - dpkg-deb --root-owner-group --build build/ pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb
    - echo "Build completed on $(date)"
  tags:
    - k3s-focal
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb

test_job:
  stage: test
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  script:
    - echo "Initiating test stage."
    - apt update && apt install -y binutils file xz-utils
    - file pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb
    - ar x pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb --output=/tmp
    - ls /tmp
    - tar -xvf /tmp/data.tar.xz -C /tmp/
    - ls -l /tmp/
    - /tmp/bin/iperf3 -v
    - find / -name iperf3 2>/dev/null
    - echo "Test completed successfully."
  tags:
    - k3s-focal

Output of test pipeline
Running with gitlab-runner 17.4.0 (b92ee590)
  on gitlab-runner-7bc46d4c54-vzxfc dAHtD6P57, system ID: r_funnNswqJhFr
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner
Using Kubernetes executor with image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:06
Using FF_USE_POD_ACTIVE_DEADLINE_SECONDS, the Pod activeDeadlineSeconds will be set to the job timeout: 1h0m0s...
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner-dahtd6p57-project-61903025-concurrent-0-iccn3kfn to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner-dahtd6p57-project-61903025-concurrent-0-iccn3kfn to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Running on runner-dahtd6p57-project-61903025-concurrent-0-iccn3kfn via gitlab-runner-7bc46d4c54-vzxfc...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/kernel.panic007/deb-pkging/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 8e4aa37e as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:01
Downloading artifacts for build_job (7942463800)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        host=cdn.artifacts.gitlab-static.net id=7942463800 responseStatus=200 OK token=glcbt-66
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:09
$ echo "Initiating test stage."
Initiating test stage.
$ apt update && apt install -y binutils file xz-utils
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [128 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [128 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [128 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [1273 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [30.9 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4036 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [4024 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1560 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [4188 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [4488 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [33.5 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [28.6 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages [55.2 kB]
Fetched 33.2 MB in 3s (11.6 MB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu libbinutils libctf-nobfd0 libctf0
  libmagic-mgc libmagic1
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu file libbinutils
  libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 xz-utils
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 2795 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmagic-mgc amd64 1:5.38-4 [218 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmagic1 amd64 1:5.38-4 [75.9 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 file amd64 1:5.38-4 [23.3 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 xz-utils amd64 5.2.4-1ubuntu1.1 [82.6 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 [208 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 [475 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libctf-nobfd0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 [48.2 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libctf0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 [46.6 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 [1614 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 [3380 B]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 2795 kB in 1s (3020 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libmagic-mgc.
(Reading database ... 4124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libmagic-mgc_1%3a5.38-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmagic-mgc (1:5.38-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmagic1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libmagic1_1%3a5.38-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.38-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package file.
Preparing to unpack .../2-file_1%3a5.38-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking file (1:5.38-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xz-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../3-xz-utils_5.2.4-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xz-utils (5.2.4-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binutils-common:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-binutils-common_2.34-6ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils-common:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbinutils:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libbinutils_2.34-6ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbinutils:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libctf-nobfd0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libctf-nobfd0_2.34-6ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libctf0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../7-libctf0_2.34-6ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libctf0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu.
Preparing to unpack .../8-binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.34-6ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binutils.
Preparing to unpack .../9-binutils_2.34-6ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Setting up libmagic-mgc (1:5.38-4) ...
Setting up binutils-common:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Setting up libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.38-4) ...
Setting up libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Setting up file (1:5.38-4) ...
Setting up xz-utils (5.2.4-1ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/xz to provide /usr/bin/lzma (lzma) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzma.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xz.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/unlzma.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/unxz.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzcat.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzcat.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzmore.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzmore.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzless.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzless.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzdiff.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzdiff.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzcmp.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzcmp.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzgrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzgrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzegrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzegrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzfgrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzfgrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
Setting up libbinutils:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Setting up libctf0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Setting up binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Setting up binutils (2.34-6ubuntu1.9) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.16) ...
$ file pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb
pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb: Debian binary package (format 2.0), with control.tar.xz, data compression xz  
$ ar x pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb --output=/tmp
$ ls /tmp
control.tar.xz
data.tar.xz
debian-binary
$ tar -xvf /tmp/data.tar.xz -C /tmp/
./
$ ls -l /tmp/
total 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 324 Sep 27 20:34 control.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 172 Sep 27 20:34 data.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4 Sep 27 20:34 debian-binary
$ /tmp/bin/iperf3 -v
/scripts-61903025-7942463801/step_script: line 172: /tmp/bin/iperf3: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1


The issue was the result of the CI directories PATH in relation to the Runner working directory. Just like in a docker container I assumed the CI working directory to be root, instead it is /builds/USER/PROJECT. Everything works now.
stages:
  - build
  - test
  
build_job:
  stage: build
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  script:
    - echo "Initiating build stage on $(date)"
    - apt update && apt install -y build-essential wget
    - wget -P /tmp https://downloads.es.net/pub/iperf/iperf-3.9.tar.gz
    - tar -xvf /tmp/iperf-3.9.tar.gz -C /tmp
    - mkdir /build pkg
    - /tmp/iperf-3.9/configure --prefix=/build
    - make && make install
    - mkdir /build/DEBIAN
    - |
      echo "Package: iperf3
      Version: 3.9-1
      Section: utils
      Priority: optional
      Architecture: all
      Maintainer: LMAO <lol@lmao.com>
      Description: iperf 3.9 test build" > /build/DEBIAN/control
    - dpkg-deb --root-owner-group --build /build pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb
    - echo "Build completed on $(date)"
  tags:
    - k3s-focal
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb

test_job:
  stage: test
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  script:
    - echo "Initiating test stage."
    - dpkg -i pkg/iperf-3.9-focal.deb
    - iperf3 -v
    - echo "Test completed successfully."
  tags:
    - k3s-focal

